# All threads get locked in wait() state

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

Basically I have to create 3 classes (2 threaded).

**First** one holds some cargo (has a minimum capacity (0) and a maximum (200))
**Second** one supplies the cargo every 500ms.
**Third** one takes away from cargo every 500ms.

Main program has one cargo class(1), 2 supplier classes(2) and 2 substraction classes(3). Problem I'm having is that one by one, they're falling into a `wait();` state and never get out. Eventually all of them get stucked in the `wait()` state, with the program running, but without them actually doing anything.

First class:

```
public class Storage {
    private int maxCapacity;
    private int currentCapacity;

    public Storage( int currentCapacity, int maxCapacity ) {
        this.currentCapacity = currentCapacity;
        this.maxCapacity = maxCapacity;
    }

    public int getCapacity(){ return this.currentCapacity; }

    public void increase( int q ) {
        this.currentCapacity += q;
        System.out.println("increase" + q + ". Total: " + currentCapacity);
    }

    public int getMax() { return this.maxCapacity; }

    public void decrease( int q ) {
        this.currentCapacity -= q;
        System.out.println("decrease - " + q + ". Total: " + currentCapacity);
    }
}
```

2nd class (supplier):

```
public class Supplier implements Runnable {
    private int capacity;
    private Storage storage;

    private volatile boolean run;

    public Supplier( int capacity, Storage storage ) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.storage = storage;
        this.run = true;
    }

    public void kiss_kill() { run = !run; }

    public synchronized void add() {
        while(storage.getCapacity() + capacity > storage.getMax()) {
            try {
                System.out.println("wait - supplier");
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        storage.increase(capacity);
        notifyAll();
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            while(run) {
                add();
                Thread.yield(); //would be wait(500), but this just speeds it up
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3rd class (taker/demander):

```
public class Taker implements  Runnable {
    private int capacity;
    private Storage storage;

    private volatile boolean run;

    public Taker( int capacity, Storage storage ) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.storage = storage;
        this.run = true;
    }

    public void kiss_kill() { run = !run; }

    public synchronized void take() {
        while(storage.getCapacity() - capacity < 0) {
            try {
                System.out.println("wait - taker");
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        storage.decrease(capacity);
        notifyAll();
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            while(run) {
                take();
                Thread.yield(); //again, wait(500) should be instead
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main is something like this:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Storage sk = new Storage(100, 200);
        Supplier[] s = { new Supplier(10, sk), new Supplier(15, sk) };
        Taker[] p = { new Taker(15, sk), new Taker(20, sk) };
        Thread t[] = {
            new Thread(s[0]),
            new Thread(s[1]),
            new Thread(p[0]),
            new Thread(p[1]) };
        for(Thread th : t) th.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60000); //program should last for 60s.
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        s[0].kiss_kill(); s[1].kiss_kill(); p[0].kiss_kill(); p[1].kiss_kill();
    }
}
```

Why doesn't notifyAll() release the wait() state of other object? What could I do to fix this?

Sorry, I know it's a long example, I hate posting too many classes like this. Thanks for reading!

**I translated the code, so if you spot anything that you're unsure about that I've missed, please tell me and I'll fix it right away!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Doing concurrency is easy:

Anyone can slap `synchronized` on methods and `synchronized () {}` around blocks of code. It does not mean it is correct. And then they can continue to slap `synchronized` on everything until it *works* until it doesn't.

#### Doing concurrency *correctly* is Hard:

You should lock on the data that needs to be consistent not the methods making the changes. And you have to use the same lock instance for everything.

In this case that is the `currentCapacity` in `Storage`. That is the only thing that is shared and the only thing that needs to be consistent.

What you are doing now is having the classes lock on instances of themselves which means nothing shared is being protected because there is no shared lock.

Think about it, if you are not locking on the same exact **instance** which must be `final` of an object then what are you protecting?

Also what about code that has access to the object that needs to be consistent and does not request a lock on it. Well it just does what it wants. `synchronized() {}` in calling classes is not how you protect shared data from external manipulation.

#### Thread safe objects are NOT about the synchronized keyword:

Read up on the `java.util.concurrent` package it has all the things you need already. Use the correct data structure for your use case.

In this particular case if you use `AtomicInteger` for your counter, you do not need any error prone manual locking, no need for `synchronized` anywhere, it is already thread safe.

#### Immutable Data:

If you work with immutable data exclusively you do not need any of this silly locking semantics that are extremely error prone for even those that understand it and even more so for those that think they understand it.

#### Here is a working idiomatic example:

This is a good chance to learn what non-deterministic means and how to use the step debugger in your IDE to debug concurrent programs.

#### [Q33700412.java](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/Q33700412.java)

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import com.vertigrated.FormattedRuntimeException;

public class Q33700412
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Storage s = new Storage(100);
        final int ap = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(ap);
        for (int i = 0; i < ap; i++)
        {
            es.execute(new Runnable()
            {
                final Random r = new Random();

                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                         /* this if/else block is NOT thread safe, I did this on purpose
                            the state can change between s.remainingCapacity() and
                            the call to s.increase/s.decrease.
                            This is ok, because the Storage object is internally consistent.
                            This thread might fail if this happens, this is the educational part.
                         */
                        if (s.remainingCapacity() > 0)
                        {
                            if (r.nextBoolean()) { s.increase(r.nextInt(10)); }
                            else { s.decrease(10); }
                            System.out.format("Current Capacity is %d", s.getCurrentCapacity());
                            System.out.println();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.format("Max Capacity %d Reached", s.getMaxCapacity());
                            System.out.println();
                        }
                        try { Thread.sleep(r.nextInt(5000)); }
                        catch (InterruptedException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        es.shutdown();
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1));
            es.shutdown();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { System.out.println("Done!"); }
    }

    public static final class Storage
    {
        /* AtomicInteger is used so that it can be mutable and final at the same time */
        private final AtomicInteger currentCapacity;
        private final int maxCapacity;

        public Storage(final int maxCapacity) { this(0, maxCapacity); }

        public Storage(final int currentCapacity, final int maxCapacity)
        {
            this.currentCapacity = new AtomicInteger(currentCapacity);
            this.maxCapacity = maxCapacity;
        }

        public int remainingCapacity() { return this.maxCapacity - this.currentCapacity.get(); }

        public int getCurrentCapacity() { return this.currentCapacity.get(); }

        public void increase(final int q)
        {
            synchronized (this.currentCapacity)
            {
                if (this.currentCapacity.get() < this.maxCapacity)
                {
                    this.currentCapacity.addAndGet(q);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new FormattedRuntimeException("Max Capacity %d Exceeded!", this.maxCapacity);
                }
            }
        }

        public int getMaxCapacity() { return this.maxCapacity; }

        public void decrease(final int q)
        {
            synchronized (this.currentCapacity)
            {
                if (this.currentCapacity.get() - q >= 0)
                {
                    this.currentCapacity.addAndGet(q * -1);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.currentCapacity.set(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Notes:

Limit the scope of `synchronized` blocks to the minimum they need to protect and lock on the object that needs to stay consistent.

The lock object ***must*** be marked `final` or the reference can change and you will be locking on different instances.

The more `final` the more correct your programs are likely to be the first time.

Comment: inside Storage? because I can't put synchronize behind the increase(int) and decrease(int) methods.

Comment: I do understand now. wait() doesn't apply to the whole program, but to the object on which I applied it from, so basically I put each object on wait() - one by one. notifyAll() calls all wait()'s on that object. But I have to admit @james large's answer showed me that, but your answer only cleared that up. upvotes to you sir, but I have to put his answer as the main one. Thank you **very** much, though!

Comment: @NemanjaT - no you do ***not get it*** based on the above comment.

Comment: I guess I'll have to put my head into it. The consistent data is being (in this example)?

Answer (score 1):

Jarrod Roberson gave you the "how" half of the answer.  Here's the other half--the "why".

Your `Supplier` object's `add()` method waits on itself (i.e., on the supplier object), and it notifies itself.

Your `Taker` object's `take()` method waits on *its* self (i.e., on the taker object), and it notifies *its* self.

The supplier never notifies the taker, and taker never notifies the supplier.

---

You should do all of your synchronization on the *shared* object (i.e., on the `Storage` object.

---

> So I should convert storage into a thread?

No, you don't want `Storage` to be a thread, you want it to be the *lock*.  Instead of having your `Supplier` objects and your `Taker` objects synchronize on themselves, they should all synchronize on the shared `Storage` object.

E.g., do this:

```
public void take() {
    synchronized(storage) {
        while(...) {
            try {
                storage.wait();
            } catch ...
        }
        ...
        storage.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Instead of this:

```
public synchronized void take() {
    while(...) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch ...
    }
    ...
    notifyAll();
}
```

And do the same for all of your other `synchronized` methods.

Comment: So I should convert storage into a thread? Because if I put synchronized behind increase and decrease (public synchronized int increase(int q) {..}), I get an exception? thanks for answering!

Comment: @NemanjaT, No, You don't want Storage to be a thread.  See my updated answer.